# Remove Woocomerce shop page

Tags: plugins

I know this question is about Woocomerce but I want to give it a try.

Is there a way to remove the shop page? I use them as parts of a custom post type, and I don't need that page, but it exists.

What is the best way to remove or hide this page from users?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716020/disable-shop-page-on-woocommerce-to-protect-categories i think you will find it here.

Comment: @Ravs, I tried that, without success. The page is still accessible by going to /shop url.

Comment: after remove it from woocommerce setting, also remove or make it draft because shop page exist in pages.

Comment: @Ravs, I also did and that. I will use then .htaccess to redirect users to index, though it's not the best solution... Thanks.

Comment: if you do not want to access shop page by /shop url than set woocommerce shop page option in settings and give it a diffrent url other than /shop (which is default)